# ReaderWriterLockSlim with LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion vs lock

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, locking, readerwriterlockslim

I am confused about the warning for `ReaderWriterLockSlim` `SupportsRecursion`

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> By default, new instances of ReaderWriterLockSlim are created with the
>   LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion flag and do not allow recursion. This
>   default policy is recommended for all new development, because
>   recursion introduces unnecessary complications and makes your code
>   more prone to deadlocks.

What I don't understand is why do this warning not apply to the built in `lock` statement which is recursive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization), the `lock` keyword in C# is based on a `Monitor` object, an *exclusive* synchronization mechanism.  "Exclusive" means that, when the first thread enters the critical section, any subsequent threads are **blocked.**

`ReaderWriterLockSlim`, on the other hand, distinguishes between *reader locks* and *writer locks.*  They are intended to be used in (and provide improved concurrency in) scenarios where there are many readers but only occasional write updates. Reader/Writer locks are *non-exclusive.*

A `lock` knows which thread it was locked on, so if that thread re-enters the critical section, it just increments a counter and continues.

A `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is in a more complicated position.  Because it distinguishes between read locks and write locks, and because it is sometimes desirable to lock on a write without creating a race condition, the ReaderWriterLockSlim offers an `UpgradableLock` that allows you to temporarily enhance the lock for write capabilities without worrying about a race condition caused by a rogue write from another thread coming in while you transition to write mode.

As you can see, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` offers a more feature-rich, but also more complex model for synchronization than `lock` does.  Its requirement to declare your intention to use recursion is an admission of this additional complexity.

**Further Reading**
[Synchronization Essentials: Locking](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking)
[Advanced Threading: Reader/Writer Locks](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Reader_Writer_Locks)
[Why Lock Recursion is Generally a Bad Idea Anyway](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/09/12/condition-variables-and-lock-recursion/)

Comment: thanks ! is there / is it possible to write a Reader/writer lock which is both recursive and upgradable ? so both threads A and thread B can each safely do enterLockRead/ enterLockRead/ enterLockWrite/ enterLockWrite/ leaveLockWrite / leaveLockWrite/ leaveLockRead / leaveLockRead  ?

Comment: I don't see why not.  However, read the last article I linked in my post.

Comment: "I don't see why not" how ? ReaderWriterLockSlim will throw exceptions trying to enter write from read ?

Comment: @kofifus: The articles I linked explain how to use ReaderWriterLockSlim in detail.